# What happens if you disable the quarantine enforcement platform before the arrival of the Sunbeam?

Tags: subnautica

It would take some serious speedrunning, but besides time I see nothing which would stop you from completing most of the main plot and deactivate the quarantine enforcement platform before the Sunbeam arrives. In that case it wouldn't make sense for the scripted event which usually happens at the Sunbeam's arrival to play out like it usually does.

Did the developers anticipate that someone would pull this off? What happens in that case?

Comment: It does not take speed-running, simply not listening to the radio stops the landing attempt until you want it, after you have deactivated the platform.

Answer (score 9):

According to [the Wiki](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Sunbeam):

> However, if the player manages to disable the Quarantine Enforcement Platform before the Sunbeam arrives, Avery Quinn will inform them that they cannot attempt a landing due to large amounts of debris orbiting the planet. Despite the Sunbeam and its crew surviving, their attempt to rescue the player still fails.

So it looks like yes this was accounted for, and you still don't get rescued by them.  They get to live, but you are still on your own.

Comment: I never succeded in saving them even by disabling the platform.  That is until the recent little.big update.  After that, if I disabled the defence platform I got the 'could not land/debris field' message.